# Generate a counter with a condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql, counter

I want to generate a counter with a condition. By `id` i want to generate a counter that start from 1 and whenever column `changer` change from x to y or y to x add 1 to the counter created.

```
 id  changer
  1       x
  1       x
  1       y
  1       x
  1       y
  2       y
  2       x
  2       y
  3       x
  3       y
  3       x
  3       y
  3       y
```

Expected result is :

```
 id  changer  counter
  1       x        1
  1       x        1
  1       y        2
  1       x        3
  1       y        4
  2       y        1
  2       x        2
  2       y        3
  3       x        1
  3       y        2
  3       x        3
  3       y        4
  3       y        4
```

Comment: These are the only columns? No date/time or other ordering?

Comment: There is date in my real base but this dataframe is already sort by date so there is no problem with that. i didnt want to add an extra column which doesnt show an extra confusion

Comment: Is this meant to be the result of a `SELECT` query, or is `id` not the primary key of your table?

Comment: the final result would be obtain the max value of this variable counter for id but i know how to obtain that from the expected result

Comment: @LucasDresl . . . What version of MySQL are you using?  And tables represent *unordered* sets.  You seem to have a specific ordering in mind.  Does a column specify that ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if you only need the maximum value, this makes things much simpler as you only need to create a counter for the rows where a change occured, and then get the max value:

```
WITH tCountAtChange as 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_time) + 1 as aCounter 
FROM
(SELECT UniqueNbr, date_time, id
,CASE WHEN LAG(changer) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_time) <> changer THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as ChangeFlag
FROM MyTable) a
WHERE ChangeFlag = 'YES')

SELECT MyTable.id, COALESCE(MAX(aCounter), 1) as MaxCounter
FROM MyTable
LEFT JOIN tCountAtChange
ON MyTable.UniqueNbr = tCountAtChange.UniqueNbr
GROUP BY MyTable.id
```

Result :

```
id  MaxCounter
 1           4
 2           3
 3           4
```

You will need a date_time field or some sort field for the ORDER BY clauses, and a UniqueNbr (Unique ID) that you can use for the join, or you could always create one in an other cte with a ROW_NUMBER function.